# Selecting rows from two tables as JSON arrays in AWS Athena

Tags: sql, join, subquery, left-join, amazon-athena

I have three tables in AWS Athena as follows:

`location`

| id | url | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | url1 | no1 |
| 2 | url2 | no2 |

`version`

| url | version | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| url1 | 1.0.0 | 2023-04-21 |
| url1 | 2.0.0 | 2023-04-26 |

`creator`

| id | email |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | e@ee.com |
| 2 | f@ee.com |
| 2 | f@ee.com |

I would like to combine these to the following format:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "url": "url1",
    "name": "no1",
    "versions": [
       {
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "date": "2023-04-21"
       },
       {
          "version": "2.0.0",
          "date": "2023-04-26"
       }
    ],
    "creators": [
       {
          "email": "e@ee.com"
       }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "url": "url2",
    "name": "no2",
    "versions": [
    ],
    "creators": [
       {
          "email": "f@ee.com"
       },
       {
          "email": "e@ee.com"
       }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have tried the following query but as it requires two left joins, it creates unnecessary rows for both versions and creators with null values:

```sql
SELECT l.id,
    ARBITRARY(l.url) AS url,
    ARBITRARY(l.name) AS name,
    CAST(
        ARRAY_AGG(
            CAST(
                ROW(
                    v.version,
                    v.date,
                ) AS ROW(
                    version VARCHAR,
                    date VARCHAR,
                )
            )
        ) AS JSON
    ) AS versions,
    CAST(
        ARRAY_AGG(
            CAST(
                ROW(
                    c.email,
                ) AS ROW(
                    email VARCHAR,
                )
            )
        ) AS JSON
    ) AS creators
FROM location l
    LEFT JOIN version v ON l.url = v.url
    LEFT JOIN creator c ON l.id = c.id
GROUP BY l.id
```

Is there any way to make this happen without the joins like using subqueries, views, or something?